# Creating proper jump mechanics in LibGDX with Box2D?

Tags: java, physics, box2d, jumping

I'm trying to create a proper jumping system for a 2D platformer with box2D, however, I'm not exactly sure how to make a good jumping system. Right now, I'm just doing

```
public void jump(float delta) {
    body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 7), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
}
```

What I want to do, is have a system like Mario's or Sonic's, where the height jumped is determined by how long the player held the jump button. How do I do something like that? Also, what's better, a rectangular box2D fixture, or an oval one? I'm sorry for such a newb question, and thank you for the help!

Comment: for a platformer like mario or sonic where you want arcade style controls, box2d may not be the best choice and it may be easier to do your own simple jumping system so you can easily customize how you want it to feel

Comment: http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/

Comment: http://s276.photobucket.com/user/jdaster64/media/smb_playerphysics.png.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMB "weakens" gravity to extend jump height when these three conditions are met:

1. You are still moving upwards.
2. You didn't release the jump button since you left the ground.
3. You didn't collect a power up.

I included a link to the documentation regarding SMB jumping physics in a comment above. The idea is that you have an initial upwards speed `s` when you hit the jump button. For instance 10m/s and as long as the previous  conditions are being met, gravity is much weaker or in Box2D terms, there is a continuous force pushing you upwards and that force is weaker than gravity, being about 70% as strong so gravity is reduced to 30% of it's usual strength.

This allows the player to fine tune the jump height.

Answer (score 1):

iforce2d to the rescue. if you can do some vector math nothing is impossible.

https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumping